# Using a QR code instead of a barcode to read a number into a web form

Tags: qr-code

I want to use generate a QR code for a docket number in a rails web app and print it on the docket. Later, a cashier will scan the QR code from the printed docket into a web form and submit it where my app will retrieve the docket record from a database using the submitted number. Is this feasible and how can I do this? The cashier may use any device from a tablet, phone or computer.

I know how to generate the required code but unsure of the feasibility of reading the code into an input form on a web page.

Comment: On one hand you can submit the qr code picture with a fileupload to your webservice and decode it server-side. But für the upload there are some phones that doesn't support the upload function.

A better option is to use phonegap as a wrapper of the side and a native qr scanner plugin.

Comment: I untagged [tag:ruby-on-rails] because the real question here is about capturing, decoding, and outputting a QR code into an HTML input field, all a client device, which Rails has nothing to do with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture image somehow.

1. http://miniqr.com/reader.php - This example use Flash & Webcam to make image and read qr code.
2. http://f.etf.unsa.ba/redmine/projects/nwt-html5-barcode-scanner - html5 solution (needs WebRTC)

Comment: I don't want to use Flash. I wonder if I can do this with HTML5/javacsript. It may be simpler to just use a bar code reader and a bar code.

Comment: @mango you didn't specify technology, so my answer was correct. I've updated with HTML5 example